# JSON arrays not working as URL variables in Chrome

Tags: php, json, get, varnish

I'm using Varnish and ESI to include a php file that has to be cached for a certain time. The URL has this structure:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com?var1=" . $var1 . "&var2=" . $var2 . "&var3=" . $var3;
```

Some variables are strings, but some are JSON arrays. Example:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/example.php?var1=[{ "ID": "123", "Name": "abc", "No": "1.2345" }],[{ "ID": "456", "Name": "def", "No": "6.7890" }]&var2=var2&var3=[{ "ID": "7889", "Name": "ghi", "No": "1.2345" }]
```

All of the variables are urlencoded, I'm writing them like this to make them more readable.

With this structure, example.php's code works well in Firefox, but doesn't work at all in Chrome. It seems that Chrome blocks all of the complex variables. Here is the output of `print_r($_GET)`:

Firefox:

```
Array
(
    [var1] => [{ "ID": "123", "Name": "abc", "No": "1.2345" }]
    [var2] => var2
    [var3] => [{ "ID": "456", "Name": "def", "No": "6.7890" }]
)
```

Chrome:

```
Array
(
    [var1] => []
    [var2] => var2
    [var3] => []
)
```

Here is the encoded `$url`:

```
http://www.example.com?var1=%5B%7B+%22ID%22%3A+%22123%22%2C+%22Name%22%3A+%22abc%22%2C+%22No%22%3A+%221.2345%22+%7D%5D%2C%5B%7B+%22ID%22%3A+%22456%22%2C+%22Name%22%3A+%22def%22%2C+%22No%22%3A+%226.7890%22+%7D%5D&var2=var2&var3=%5B%7B+%22ID%22%3A+%227889%22%2C+%22Name%22%3A+%22ghi%22%2C+%22No%22%3A+%221.2345%22+%7D%5D
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to pass such URL variables to Chrome?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Include also the URL-encoded format of url with JSON, just to see if there is any error there.

Comment: I have now added URL-encoded format of the URL.

Comment: That encoded $url does not match non-encoded example. For example `var1` is `[{ "ID": "123", "Name": "abc", "No": "1.2345" }],[{ "ID": "456", "Name": "def", "No": "6.7890" }]`

Comment: I know, I have added it to show that arrays can contain multiple items. I have adjusted everything now.

Comment: Perhaps try using `http_build_query` which can build query-strings from complex data.

Comment: Thank you Markus, that worked.